# Horizontal Tab in Unicode

Tags: html, unicode

I have a function which stores a string that has read off a StreamReader. The file in question contains horizontal tabs, which I know are registered as U+0009 in Unicode. I'd like to display the string in HTML, which involves some conversion obviously.

The code I've used to attempt this conversion is

```
readResults = readResults.Replace(ChrW(&H9), "&#09;")
```

Unfortunately, no love. The tab is removed as is expected of any whitespace characters left undealt with. Any ideas?

EDIT: 
Figured it out

```
readResults = readResults.Replace(vbTab, "<pre>&#09;</pre>")
```

Comment: You could try replacing them with a em space &#8195; or &#x2003; (or if you like to no support older browsers &emsp;). The are the wides available spaces I could find.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `white-space:pre-wrap` CSS property to your HTML element. This property will force all white-space (including tabs) to appear. When you also want to preserve newlines, use `white-space:pre`.

Comment: Turns out I already had pre-wrap set in my CSS. I then tried to manually set it using javascript, and the text still shows up untabbed. I believe the same thing happened with pre for my newlines, so I have a similar snippet like Replace(vbNewLine, "<br/>"). The &#09; entity should be fine; the issue likely lies within my incorrect syntax for the detection of horizontal tabbing in VB.

Comment: Are you sure that the characters in the source are actually tabs? Copy a substring, and use this bookmarklet: `javascript:alert(escape(prompt("-1 = no tab character found","")).indexOf("\x09"))`

Comment: Well, they are text files which I created myself, so I know for certain that certain lines contain whitespace generated by a physical keypress of the tab button.

Comment: It was written in Notepad in Windows, though I just checked the file and it was saved as ANSI rather than Unicode. That said, I always thought StreamReader read bytes using Unicode by default.